# How to send AccessToken in Server Components

Tags: next.js, nestjs, authorization, access-token, next.js14

I have the following situation. Using Next 14, I have a component that I want to render on the server side, fetching data from an API in NestJS. The problem arises when sending data with axios; I need to set the Authorization Header as Bearer and add the AccessToken from the client side. Considering that there is no localStorage or sessionStorage in server-side components, I'm not sure how to resolve this issue.
`
import React from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

import TableContracts from '@/components/tablecontracts.components'

export default async function Page() {

```
const results = await axios.get('http://localhost:3001/empresas/listado-empresas', {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${'Aqui deberia ir el accessToken'}`
            }
        });

const columns = [
    {name: 'ID', uid: 'id'},
    {name: "Nombre", uid: 'nombre'},
    {name: "Alias", uid: 'alias'},
    {name: "Telefono", uid: 'telefono'},
    {name: "Representante", uid: 'representante'},
    {name: "Direccion", uid: 'direccion'},
    {name: "Cuenta", uid: 'cuenta'},
    {name: "Acciones", uid: 'actions'},
  ];
```

return (

<TableContracts columns={columns} users={results} isAdmin={false} key={'tablecontractuid'} />

)
}

`

To know the correct way to handle the access token in components that are rendered on the server side. The fastest solution is to have it as a component rendered on the client side, but I want to use the features of Next 14.